# I can't find Manaphy in Pokemon Legends Arceus

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

I finished all the tasks, even unlocked the cave, but Manaphy isn't there. I already repeated the process many times, he's not there.
Any help?

Comment: So you heard its cry when traversing the two spikes emerging from the sea? What's the current state of Laventon's request? Is it marked as completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, I was missing a requirement.

You have to have Buizel, Overquil and Mantyke in your team, and THEN go through the gate.

Comment: For those interested to know why you need these Pokémon, it's in reference in a book having the same name as the quest that you can find in Pokemon BDSP